# Laravel many-to-many relation with custom table names and IDs

Tags: laravel, migration, many-to-many, entity-relationship

Hello so I have many to many relation between Question [table name: **tblquestion**, id: **que_id**] and Agecategory [table name: **tblagecategory**, id: **aca_id**]. They have shared table named QuestionAgecategory [table name: **tblquestionagecategory**, id: **qac_id**].

*I want to note that all the IDS and table names are custom named and not according to typical Laravel syntax.*

And I am trying to relate them in Laravel. So far it returns null when I try to look $question->agecategories;

> > > $question->agecategories;
> > >       => null

But it has records in it and returns this after $question = App\Question::find(1);

> > > $question = App\Question::find(1);
> > >       => App\Question {#2901
> > >            que_id: 1,
> > >            que_name: "hello",

### Question model

```php
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tblquestion';
    protected $primaryKey = 'que_id';
    protected $keyType = 'integer'; 
    public $incrementing = true;
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function agecategories() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Agecategory');
    }
}
```

### Agecategory model

```php
class Agecategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tblagecategory';
    protected $primaryKey = 'aca_id';
    protected $keyType = 'integer'; 
    public $incrementing = true;

    public function questions() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question');
    }
}
```

### QuestionAgecategory model

```php
class QuestionAgecategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tblquestionagecategory';
    protected $primaryKey = 'qac_id';
    protected $keyType = 'integer'; 
    public $incrementing = true;
}
```

### Migrations

```php
      Schema::create('tblquestion', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('que_id');
          $table->string('que_name', 128);
      });


      Schema::create('tblagecategory', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('aca_id');
          $table->timestamps();
      });

      Schema::create('tblquestionagecategory', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('qac_id');
          $table->integer('qac_que_id')->unsigned();
          $table->integer('qac_aca_id')->unsigned();
          $table->foreign('qac_que_id')->references('que_id')->on('tblquestion');
          $table->foreign('qac_aca_id')->references('aca_id')->on('tblagecategory');
      });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using custom columns and custom database naming.

Your Belongs to many is expecting a pivot table `tblquestion_tblagecategory` which does not exist. As the previos answer stated, you should change your belongsToMany to search for the custom tables and columns.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Change to this in your question Model

```php
public function agecategories() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Agecategory', 'tblquestionagecategory', 'qac_que_id', 'qac_aca_id');
}
```

And also, in your other Agecategory Model

```php
public function questions() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'tblquestionagecategory', 'qac_aca_id', 'qac_que_id');
}
```

Comment: I still get this error: $agecategory->questions;
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not
found: 1146 Table 'yamldb.agecategory_question' doesn't exist (SQL: select `tblquestion`.*, `agecategory_question`.`agecategory_aca_id` as `pivot_agecategory_aca_id`, `agecategory_question`.`question_que_id` as `pivot_question_que_id` from `tblquestion` inner join `agecategory_question` on `tblquestion`.`que_id` = `agecategory_question`.`question_que_id` where `agecategory_question`.`agecategory_aca_id` = 1)'

Comment: thats when you make this changes? that's weird, because you are defining the table name 'tblquestionagecategory' and thats what it should look for...

Comment: Yeah  I know. And I really can't do much about it because I am getting these table names and all the details from the yaml file so that's why the table names are not usual to Laravel syntax.

Also I messed a bit with the ID's (first I tried your solution and then I tried adding ID from the Questions table and connect it with the ID in the tblquestionagecategory's ID

   `public function questions() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'tblquestionagecategory', 'aca_id', 'qac_aca_id');
    }`

But that also didn't work.

Comment: im taking a long shot... but maybe composer dumpauto or php artisan dump-autoload

Comment: Now I am getting this error. I mean now at least it looks into right table?
`>>> $question->agecategories;
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
Unknown column 'tblquestionagecategory.que_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `tblagecategory`.*, `tblquestionagecategory`.`que_id` as `pivot_que_id`, `tblquestionagecategory`.`qac_que_id` as `pivot_qac_que_id` from `tblagecategory` inner join `tblquestionagecategory`
on `tblagecategory`.`aca_id` = `tblquestionagecategory`.`qac_que_id` where `tblquestionagecategory`.`que_id` = 1)'`

Comment: No, belongsToMany needs: 1 Related Model, 2 Specific pivot table (which works now) 3 foreign key of pivot table for Left side of the relation Model, 4 foreign key of pivot table for Related Model (1)   ---  it should be 'App\Question', 'tblquestionagecategory', 'qac_aca_id', 'qac_que_id'

Comment: yah I know i switched it back to these keys but it still takes the old values even after I tried `composer dump-autoload` again . But the function from the Agecategory works! So it is just from the Question model function that still is stubborn. But  I will mark this reply as my question answer :)

Comment: Always recheck, also, if you are using homestead... (it shouldnt but) there may be some lag updating the files you modify outside homestead into homestead.

Comment: Hey I know it's been a while but i was wondering do I need to specify any relations in the middle model - QuestionAgecategory ?

Answer (score 0):

add below relationship function in Question model

```php
public function agecategories() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Agecategory', 'tblquestionagecategory', 'qac_que_id', 'qac_aca_id');
}
```

Comment: it still returns null even when I added the tblquestionagecategory and the keys. I was thinking that i needed to add the table. but it is really tricky with custom names making relations work. do i need to define something in the QuestionAgecategory model maybe?

Comment: QuestionAgecategory model is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem but I had to declare only the foreign keys without a prefix like this:

```
public function agecategories() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Agecategory', 'tblquestionagecategory', 'que_id', 'aca_id');
}
```